# Make text outside div invisible

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have got problem with word wrapping in div.
I am trying to make something like that:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrJlb.png), but i have got this: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7kU9.png). This is my code:

```css
#div-1 {
  height: 28px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}
#span-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066FF;
  line-height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
    <span id="span-1"> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText </span>
</div>
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use white-space in combination with overflow. And text-overflow if you like. See the example below.

```css
    #div-1 {
      height: 28px;
      width: 250px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
      
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #0066FF;
      line-height: 28px;
     
      /* Does the magic */
      overflow :hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      
      text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Adds the ... */
    }
```

```html
    <div id="div-1">
        SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best option

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow` property to your `div` style:

```
#div-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from `#span-1` and add `overflow-x: hidden;` for `#div-1`. You can also use **`text-overflow: ellipsis;`** which adds ... if the text overflows.

```css
#div-1 {
  height: 28px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#span-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066FF;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
    <span id="span-1"> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Make #div-1 position:relative and add overflow:hidden property.

CSS

```
#div-1 {
  height: 28px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#span-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066FF;
  line-height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div-1">
    <span id="span-1"> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText </span>
</div>
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div-1 {
  height: 28px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  overflow:hidden;
}
#span-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066FF;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
    <span id="span-1"> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this:
word-wrap: break-word;